# Tradeoffs between RESTful GET and querystring serialization

Tags: rest, http

We have several microservices and are now in a position where we need a GET request with a list of ID's in a querystring.

I'm reluctant to use a POST for the purposes of a GET request because of the general principal of using HTTP verbs as intended.

However, there are plenty of drawbacks to serializing our array of ID's in the querystring:
1. querystring limits on the server and in the browser
2. having to add our own serialization code to put the array into the querystring
3. deserializing on the server

**Is it overly dogmatic to strictly adhere to the GET / POST definitions? Am I correct in assuming that using a POST in order to GET data back (not changing the state of the server) is the most sensible option here?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> REST is intended for long-lived network-based applications that span multiple organizations. If you don’t see a need for the constraints, then don’t use them. -- [Fielding, 2008](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven#comment-742)

You *can* use POST for everything, if you like.  [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) did that, and more recently GraphQL leans that way as well.

But what you give up are the properties that arise from the more restrictive constraints of GET.  Two of these are that GET requests are [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) and [cacheable](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234).

Safe means that general-purpose components can know that there is no danger in retrying a lot request; on an unreliable network, they can autonomously resend a request if the response is lost.

Caching, of course, means that we have widely understood semantics that no only describe if something can be cached, but for how long, and when they should be invalidated.

Essentially, using POST for everything reduces HTTP from an [application protocol](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s) to a transport protocol.

Answer (score 0):

There is a precedent for allow POST to provide a search request object and get back search results, so I think it's a reasonable thing to do.

For example, the Elasticsearch query API:

```
POST /twitter/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html

Another option is to provide a body with a GET, but you have to be aware that some clients won't be able to support that. In the elasticsearch documentation, they indicate that they support both:

> Both HTTP GET and HTTP POST can be used to execute search with body.
>   Since not all clients support GET with body, POST is allowed as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually built into many frameworks. The trick is to duplicate the parameter like ?id=1&id=5&id=10

You did not specify any frameworks, but ASP.NET(and dotnet core) and angular all have support for this.